# Eclipse add tabhost to project error

Tags: android, eclipse, android-tabhost

When I am trying to add a TabHost using

```
RightClick > New > Android XML > Select Root Element :TabHost
```

It shows tabhost need a tabwidget and frame layout.

Actually tabhost is the root. How I can have a **tabwidget** and **frame layout** before ?

Is that fault of eclipse or mine ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to create layout with root TabHost as you described on eclipse 3.7.1 with no errors. I belive as workaround you can create layout with LinearLayout as root and then either put TabHost inside it or switch LinearLayout with TabHost.

**edit:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent">
   <TabWidget
      android:id="@android:id/tabs"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content">
   </TabWidget>
   <FrameLayout
      android:id="@android:id/tabcontent" 
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content">
   </FrameLayout>  
</TabHost>
```

Comment: I have tried to change LinearLayout to tabhost It again shows like this :: TabHost requires a TabWidget with id "android:id/tabs".

Exception details are logged in Window > Show View > Error Log :: But adding the tabHost under the linearlayout works fine. thanks

Comment: glad that worked. have you tried adding TabWidget and FrameLayout to xml file directly?

Comment: No when I add tabhost under linearlayout they all automatically added

Comment: You need to put the id the for the tabhost in the above layout android:id="@android:id/tabhost"

Comment: Switching my layout also not worked but when I Typed or pasted the whole thing from a xml with tabhost it works..

Answer (score 1):

This feature should work as you described after installing ADK 2.3.3 update 2, using Eclipse 3.7.1.